# Browsing two browsers one with mouse and other with webdriver

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, manual-testing

I'd like to know if this is feasible: I'm doing manual testing on a website but I'd like to test the website on Chrome and Firefox at the same time, so is there a way to mimic my mouse clicks and keyboard input on from Chrome to Firefox using webdriver or any other technology?

Edit:
More info as asked in the comment.
I work as a tester, and I've written some E2E tests using webdriver.io and I know that I can run my test on multiple browsers concurrently using [multiremote](http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/multiremote.html).
I have tried tests recorders too since a long time ago and didn't find much luck, and what I'm trying to do can be partially accomplished with some tests recording services, by recording the tests and then running them on multiple environments. 
However what I'm trying to find is a way to read the actions of the user from one browser say Chrome, and apply them on another, so I imagine this will involve finding the selector and the action applied and applying them in the other browser.
I know I can write the tests or record them, but it was just an idea, and it would be great to have it for exploratory testing on multiple browsers at the same time, when I googled it all I got was writing scripts or recording, so I wanted to ask experienced people about their experience, and I think I could have posted this in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/ however it's more related to programming than to QA, so I needed programmers.

P.S: I'll try editing the question more to make it more readable. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the links, actually I'm a tester and a CS graduate, and I've worked in test automation using webdriver.io and I had this specific scenario in mind that I know is most probably not possible so I only was asking to check if anyone has done something similar before, however I'll try to explain what I know.

Comment: @JeffC, I hope I made it better not worse.

Comment: What you are talking about is essentially record and playback. Why does it have to be mirroring actions at the same time?

Comment: @JeffC, as I mentioned in the edit, it would be great for exploratory testing, because it's much more valuable than automated testing (in my opinion and James Bach's) and we usually do ET on one browser so it would be great to have multiple browsers open and mimicking the actions.

Comment: So why not record your actions on one browser, turn the recording into code and run it on other browsers? It doesn't seem from your comment that it has to be done at the same time, just repeat the manual actions on other browsers to save effort/time.

Comment: I think this is the best option I have for now, although there's still an advantage of what I'm looking for and that's noticing something in the other browser in real time and changing the test accordingly, however for now I think the best I can do is record the test and run it on multiple browsers using some recording service as you said.